# How can I store Google Maps search results in an array?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, google-maps

I'm working on an app where I need to query Google for businesses near a current location. How do I go about storing them in an array? I don't want to exit the app and open Google Maps, I want to be able to display the addresses in a list format (Table View, I suppose).

I'm using MapKit.

I send this url to Google:

```
NSString *url    =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=ChevyDealers&near=%@",
[fullAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I verified that it works by launching Google Maps with the URL built here. This is not the functionality that I want in the end product though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapKit is really only going to let you plot and display the locations.  You are most likely going to need to use the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) in order to get straight results.
Once you create your API URL, and get your results back, you can then put them in an array and send that data to a UITableView.